# Sort by Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to sort my custom post type `packages` with a advanced custom field `package_order_id`:

[image]

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'packages',
    'meta_key' => 'package_order_id',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));    
while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
```

I've resulted to this after searching for other answers and I still can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/ ?

Comment: Yes, it was the first thing I looked at.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be using `global $wp_query;` at all, but would be running arguments through a new query using WP Query.

```
<?php 
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'packages',
    'meta_key'  => 'package_order_id',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'DESC'
));   
// loop
if( $posts ) {  
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {        
        setup_postdata( $post );

        // do something   
    }   
    wp_reset_postdata();        
}  
?>
```